# Sitecore "personalize" button access for non Admin users

Tags: permissions, sitecore, personalization

Our CMS content editors are not configured as Sitecore Admin users. The content editors don't have access to the "Personalize" button in the Device editor. The users are added to a custom sitecore role which are inherited from these Sitecore roles :

Sitecore\Designer

Sitecore\Author

Sitecore\Sitecore Client Authoring

Is there any other role that this custome role should inherit from, to get the access to the personalize button ? The users who are configured as admin are able to view this button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the role Analytics Personalization.

There's a great post here on the built in roles and what they do

http://reyrahadian.com/2015/03/19/sitecore-built-in-security-roles/

Comment: Thanks Golden, adding our custom role as member of "Analytics Personalization" role resolved the issue. It seems that there is an issue with the upgrade process from sitecore 6.4 version to 7.1 version. I don't see the Analytics Personalization role by default. I had to package it from a new instance of sitecore 7.1 version and install it.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it sorted.